# Cannot add providers in Hermes JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Following the guide [here](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Managing+Providers) I have added the Active Mq Jars to providers list:
[image]

But Hermes Jms does not show the Active Mq connection factory:
[image]

I have tried restarting Hermes Jms but that doesn't help.

Comment: Sadly this URL takes you to a dodgy malware / fake support page now (like so much with HermesJMS). 

Could the link be removed please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you need to change the Loader dropdown in the middle section of the Session screen from System to ActiveMQ.  I have the setup steps documented in a word doc and can send them to you if you send me your email address. (my id is mikemil@hotmail.com)  The instructions were originally written for Weblogic, but you can take basically the same steps and modify slightly for ActiveMQ.

The gist is

1. create your context for ActiveMQ
2. then when you create the session, the ConnectionFactory loaded needs to be switched to ActiveMQ from System.  This allows Hermes to find the active mq connection factory.  By doing that, now Hermes can find the ActiveMQ connection factory options.  See my screenshot below.

Hope this helps!

[image]